# IEquatable Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: c#, linq, unity-container, iequatable

Ad I'm developping a project in C# I recently came over an error I can't understand.

First of all here is the core

```
if (CanPlay(target.Coord.X, target.Coord.Y))
{
    target.Owner = m.Player;
    this.MoveList.Push(m);
    // Groupes
    var friends = GetAround(target).FindAll(i => i.Owner == target.Owner);

    Groupe g = new Groupe { target };
    foreach (Intersection fr in friends)
    {
        g.AddRange(GetGroupe(fr));
    }
    foreach (Intersection fr in friends)
    {
        this.Groupes.Remove(GetGroupe(fr));
    }
    this.Groupes.Add(g);
}
```

And here is the getGroupe function that causes the problem :

```
Groupe GetGroupe(Intersection i)
{
    return this.Groupes.First(g => g.Contains(i));
}
```

So, at some random moments, when a move is done, I get the IEquatable Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
Here is the stack trace :

```
InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object
System.Linq.Enumerable.First[Groupe] (IEnumerable`1 source, System.Func`2 predicate, Fallback fallback)

System.Linq.Enumerable.First[Groupe] (IEnumerable`1 source, System.Func`2 predicate)

Assets.ObjetsDeJeu.Goban.GetGroupe (Assets.ObjetsDeJeu.Intersection i) (at Assets/ObjetsDeJeu/Goban.cs:155)
Assets.ObjetsDeJeu.Goban.PutRock (Assets.ObjetsDeJeu.Move m) (at Assets/ObjetsDeJeu/Goban.cs:142)
```

So the line 142 is

```
g.AddRange(GetGroupe(fr));
```

and 155 is

```
return this.Groupes.First(g => g.Contains(i));
```

I don't understand since the this.Groupes is only empty at the very begenning. I did a test where I checked if it was empty before looking for a group but it didn't change anything ...

Comment: Please provide the definition of `Groupe` and `Intersection`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the call to `First()` with the specified predicate does not yield any result. Use `FirstOrDefault` instead and check for `null`. 
Change your code as follows to fix the problem:

```
foreach (Intersection fr in friends)
{
    var group = GetGroupe(fr);
    if(group != null)
       g.AddRange(group);
}
foreach (Intersection fr in friends)
{
   var group = GetGroupe(fr);
   if(group != null)
     this.Groupes.Remove(group);
}


Groupe GetGroupe(Intersection i)
{
   return this.Groupes.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Contains(i));
}
```